# Variable in PHP class coming up as null

Tags: php

I have a Survey class that has multiple functions.

In one of the functions, I check if a survey exists - and if not, call the **other** function that creates and returns a new survey.

Like this:

```
public function createSurvey($userId) {
     somecode...
     return $surveyId;
}
```

The other function goes like this:

```
public function getExistingSurvey($userId) {
     $survey = $this->checkIfSurveyExists($userId)...
     if (!$survey) {
         return $this->createSurvey($userId);
     }
}
```

The problem I am running into, seems to be a scope issue with the `$userId` variable.

When I call the `getExistingSurvey()` function, I am asking for:

a) Return an existing survey entry
b) ELSE create a new one and return it

The function DOES return an existing survey, if it exists and passes the `$userId` variable just fine.

However if it does not exist and I need to create one with the `createSurvey($userId)` function, then it somehow sends over a `null` value for the `$userId`.

It seems to be a scope issue.

Any ideas? ...

Comment: Are you perhaps assigning a null in checkIfSurveyExists to the $userID var? I was not able to re-create it with the example you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not returning the existing survey. If it exists you miss the if which does not return which is implicitly returning null

Comment: That's what I told him yesterday :/

Comment: You said he was comparing to true ? They are not the same

Comment: Second Comment "... getExistingSurvey() doesnt return anything unless survey is set which would implicitly return NULL. "

Comment: Ah I didn't see that either, Should have moved it to the answer :)

Comment: It's OK,... just my ego,.. slight bruising.  Reminds me of my marriage. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using $survey to store the results of checkIfSurveyExists() but checking $value for true.

```
public function getExistingSurvey($userId) {
     $survey = $this->checkIfSurveyExists($userId)...
     if (!$value) {
         return $this->createSurvey($userId);
     }
}
```

Comment: yeah that was stupid. Honestly, the run-time code does not have that error. When putting on the site, I mis-entered it. I wish it were that simple! Any other ideas? ... (I just fixed the original post - thanks for pointing that out)

Comment: Theres a couple things,... but without the full code, poking in the dark.  for example getExistingSurvey() doesnt return anything unless survey is set which would implicitly return NULL.

Comment: createSurvey: only code we have is userid is passed in and surveyId is returned,... how is surveyID being determined?  The function implies it's creating a survey not return a survey's ID.